# Error while trying to access database after updating WAMP

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, wamp

I updated WAMP and after the update im unable to retrieve any data from my database.

I get the following error:

```
( ! ) Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'cookieb1_root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in C:\wamp64\www\testground\php\fetch_lista_productos_compra.php on line 5
Call Stack
#TimeMemoryFunctionLocation
10.0000407392{main}(  )...\testground.php:0
20.0000408352require( 'C:\wamp64\www\testground\php\fetch_lista_productos_compra.php' )...\testground.php:163
30.0000408352mysqli_connect
(  )...\fetch_lista_productos_compra.php:5

( ! ) Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, bool given in C:\wamp64\www\testground\php\fetch_lista_productos_compra.php on line 7
Call Stack
#TimeMemoryFunctionLocation
10.0000407392{main}(  )...\testground.php:0
20.0000408352require( 'C:\wamp64\www\testground\php\fetch_lista_productos_compra.php' )...\testground.php:163
30.0150409368mysqli_query
(  )...\fetch_lista_productos_compra.php:7

( ! ) Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in C:\wamp64\www\testground\php\fetch_lista_productos_compra.php on line 9
Call Stack
#TimeMemoryFunctionLocation
10.0000407392{main}(  )...\testground.php:0
20.0000408352require( 'C:\wamp64\www\testground\php\fetch_lista_productos_compra.php' )...\testground.php:163
30.0150409368mysqli_fetch_assoc
(  )...\fetch_lista_productos_compra.php:9
```

I have checked my username and password a thousand times already and they are ok, i also audited the database and table permissions and everything checks out.

These are a few captures from phpmyadmin:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Im ran out of ideas to solve this, any kind of help will be greatly appreciated and as always thank you for your time.

I hope i provided enough information if not please let me know.

Comment: These errors are regarding php script please provide your php code.

Comment: SOLVED: I added the port number for mySQL in the *db_key.php* file *$servername = "localhost:3308";*

Comment: If it's solved then create your own answer (and accept it) so that this question is marked as resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED: I added the port number for mySQL in the **db_key.php** file **$servername = "localhost:3308"**